# Accessing .mock property of an automocked function

Tags: jestjs, automocking

I have this code:

```
import * as a from 'a-a';
jest.mock('a-a');

describe('a-a', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const x = await a.x(1); // Calls the mock
        console.log(x);   // 1
        console.log(a.x.mock) // Undefined
    });
});
```

The mock function is:

```
export async function x(data) {
    cache.push(data);

    console.log('HERE'); // this is printed

    return data;
}
```

The mock of the module is in the `__mocks__` directory.

The `a.x()` calls the mocked function, but `a.x.mock` is undefined.

How is that possible? Where is the `.mock` property?

Comment: What do you get when logging `a.x`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle `[Function: x]`. Maybe relevant, `x` is `async`

Comment: Would it be a solution to mock it like this: `jest.mock('a-a', () => ({x: jest.fn()}))` . Its a bit more to write but at least this will work.

Comment: I also wonder how your example works, cause I thought it would mock the module with a function that returns `undefined`.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I'd prefer to have the automock. No the mocked function actually return something, I updated the question

Comment: So could you post your mock then?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle it is already in the question, I updated before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some investigation I found out that the functions declared in the `__mocks__` directory aren't wrapped by `jest.fn()` by default.

Personally I find the thing a bit confusing.

So you can do both

```
function x(data) {
    cache.push(data);

    return cache;
}

jest.mock('a-a', () => ({x: x}))
```

if you do everything in the same file, or

```
jest.mock('a-a');
```

and then in the `__mocks__/a-a.js` file

```
export const x = jest.fn(async (data) => {
    cache.push(data);

    return cache;
});
```